# @Transaction is not working in spring boot 2.x and i am getting "Executing an update/delete query" while updating table

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

When I am using `session.beginTransaction()` then table getting updated but unable to rollback when anywhere stuck. By removing `session.beginTransaction()` I found the table is not updating and I am getting "Executing an update/delete query" exception at the console. Please find below full stack track.

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1580)
    at com.skilrock.jackpot.dao.impl.JackpotDaoImpl.updateCurrentValue(JackpotDaoImpl.java:159)
    at com.skilrock.jackpot.dao.impl.JackpotDaoImpl.getSetDetail(JackpotDaoImpl.java:91)
    at com.skilrock.jackpot.dao.impl.JackpotDaoImpl.getJackpot(JackpotDaoImpl.java:47)
    at com.skilrock.jackpot.dao.impl.JackpotDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bdef8e95.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.skilrock.jackpot.dao.impl.JackpotDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1280fb7b.getJackpot(<generated>)
    at com.skilrock.jackpot.service.impl.JackpotServiceImpl.getJackpot(JackpotServiceImpl.java:21)
    at com.skilrock.jackpot.service.impl.JackpotServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6bee6d5b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.skilrock.jackpot.service.impl.JackpotServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$47a38826.getJackpot(<generated>)
    at com.skilrock.jackpot.controller.JackpotController.contribution(JackpotController.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

```
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.company.jackpot.beans.RequestBean;
    import com.company.jackpot.beans.ResponseBean;
    import com.company.jackpot.dao.JackpotDao;
    import com.company.jackpot.service.JackpotService;
    @Service
    public class JackpotServiceImpl implements JackpotService {

        @Autowired
        private JackpotDao jackpotDao;
        @Override
        @Transactional
        public ResponseBean getJackpot(RequestBean requestBean) {

            ResponseBean responseBean = jackpotDao.getJackpot(requestBean);
            return responseBean;
        }

    }
```

---

```
package com.company.jackpot.util;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateUtilConfig {
    /*@Value("${db.driver}")
    private String DRIVER;*/

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String PASSWORD;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String URL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String USERNAME;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String DIALECT;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String SHOW_SQL;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String HBM2DDL_AUTO;

    @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
    private String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       // dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", DIALECT);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", SHOW_SQL);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HBM2DDL_AUTO);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}




package com.company.jackpot.dao.impl;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.company.jackpot.beans.RequestBean;
import com.company.jackpot.beans.ResponseBean;
import com.company.jackpot.dao.JackpotDao;
import com.company.jackpot.model.CurrentValue;
import com.company.jackpot.model.TransactionMaster;
import com.company.jackpot.model.TransactionWin;
import com.company.jackpot.model.enummodel.Level;
import com.company.jackpot.util.CommonOperation;

@Repository
//@Transactional(rollbackOn = {ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class})
public class JackpotDaoImpl implements JackpotDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    ResponseBean responseBean = new ResponseBean();

    @Override
    public ResponseBean getJackpot(RequestBean requestBean) {

        Session session = null;
        //Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            //session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            //tx = session.beginTransaction();

            String hql = "select setId from SetReference where serviceCode = '" + requestBean.getServiceCode()
                    + "' and gameCode = " + requestBean.getGameCode() + "";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            List<Integer> queryResultList = query.list();
            if (!queryResultList.isEmpty()) {

                int setId = queryResultList.get(0);
                getSetDetail(setId, requestBean, session);
                //int i = 2;

                //session.getTransaction().commit();
                //tx.commit();

                return responseBean;
            } else {
                responseBean.setErrorCode(401);
                responseBean.setErrorMsg("You are not eligible for jackpot");
//              session.getTransaction().commit();
                return responseBean;
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void getSetDetail(int setId, RequestBean requestBean, Session session) {

        try {
            String setDetailQuery = "select setId, level, type, contributionPercentage, startRange, endRange from SetDetail where setId = "
                    + setId + "";
            Query query = session.createQuery(setDetailQuery);
            List<Object[]> setDetailQueryList = query.list();
            if (!setDetailQueryList.isEmpty()) {
                for (Object[] setDetail : setDetailQueryList) {
                    // SetDetail setDetail = (SetDetail)set;
                    Double start = (double) setDetail[4];
                    Double end = (double) setDetail[5];
                    int randomNumber = CommonOperation.getRandomNumber(start.intValue(), end.intValue());
                    Double contributionPercentage = (double) setDetail[3];
                    Double contributionValue = CommonOperation.getContributionValue(requestBean.getBetAmount(),
                            contributionPercentage.intValue());
                    if (setDetail[1].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("MACHINE")) {
                        /*
                         * from here take random and contribution and then update current_value table
                         * txn_master, txn_win
                         */
                        System.out.println(setDetail[1]);
                        updateCurrentValue((int) setDetail[0], setDetail[1].toString(), setDetail[2].toString(),
                                randomNumber, contributionValue, requestBean.getMachineId(), requestBean, session);

                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateCurrentValue(int setId, String level, String type, int randomNumber, double contributionValue,
            String levelId, RequestBean requestBean, Session session) {
            long transactionId;

        try {
            String hql = "from CurrentValue where setId = " + setId + " and level = '" + level + "' and levelId = '"
                    + levelId + "'";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            List<CurrentValue> currentValueList = query.list();
            for (CurrentValue currentValue : currentValueList) {
                System.out.println(currentValue);

                if (currentValue.getEligiblePrice() == null) {
                    responseBean.setJackpotType(null);
                    responseBean.setWinningAmount(null);
                    String updateHQl = "update CurrentValue set eligiblePrice = :price, totalContributionValue = :value where setId = "
                            + setId + " and level = '" + level + "' and levelId = '" + levelId + "'";

                    Query updateQuery = session.createQuery(updateHQl);
                    updateQuery.setParameter("price", (double) randomNumber);
                    updateQuery.setParameter("value", (currentValue.getTotalContributionValue() + contributionValue));
                    int rowsAffected = updateQuery.executeUpdate();
                    if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                        System.out.println(rowsAffected + " Affected");
                        // now update txn_master, txn_win
                        transactionId = updateTransactionMaster(setId, requestBean, session);
                        System.out.println(5/0);



                }   }
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am expecting tables get updated and if any exception comes all the entries must be rollback by using `@Transaction`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@Transactional` which is Container Managed but also manually starting a session in the `@Repository`. This messes things up.

Do not open the session explicitly in that case. By default, all the `RuntimeExceptions` will result in a rollback. If you want to rollback on a checked exception then you need to configure that on the `@Transactional` annotation level.

Comment: If explicitly session is not an option then how can I get the session object. If you can explain by any sample code then please share

Answer (score 1):

You are using Spring Boot (according to the tags you added), however your code and configuration show that you are trying very hard to work around the framework.

Ditch your `HibernateUtilConfig` and instead add the following the the `application.properties`.

```
spring.datasource.url= // value of current db.url
spring.datasource.username= // value of current db.username
spring.datasource.password= // value of current db.password

spring.jpa.database-platform= // value of hibernate.dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql= // value of hibernate.show_sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= // value of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
```

This is the replacement of your `HibernateUtilConfig` and assumes that your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in a top-level package. If not add an `@EntityScan` (although it is recommended to put it in a top-level package).

Then instead of the `SessionFactory` and `Session` use JPA with the `EntityManager` in your repository.

```
@Repository
public class JackpotDaoImpl implements JackpotDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
```

Now you can use the `EntityManager` instead of the `Session`.

Your code is also flawed

1. You are using String concat to create queries, **never** use concat to create queries, use named parameter when using Hibernate / JPA
2. Your dao isn't thread-safe because you are reusing a class level `ResponseBean`, remove it from the class and create it when needed in the method itself.
3. You are using Hibernate / JPA but are using plain queries to run updates, that basically beats the purpose of using an ORM. Update the entities and let hibernate worry about the rest.
4. You are doing a try/catch inside your repository method, this will  break proper tx management.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution the issue is in MySQL Database engine. My engine was MYIsam which does not support rollback Transactions. I changed my DB engine to InnoDB and Now it is working fine.

alter table table_name ENGINE = INNODB;

Answer (score 0):

You should add `@Transactional` annotation to your methods of Update or delete query.

for example in your **updateCurrentValue** method it sould be like that :

```
@Transactional
public void updateCurrentValue(...){
    //...
}
```